# sharing variables between beanshell scripts

Tags: variables, shared, beanshell

I want to have some kind of an initialization in 1 particular beanshell script , which is later used in 2 other bsh scripts. Now , the initialization thus takes place twice.

Is there some way to share variables/namespace between beanshell scripts so that the initialization takes place only once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the object "bsh.shared".

```
if(bsh.shared.myList == void)
  bsh.shared.myList = new java.util.ArrayList();

// Do stuff to the List anywhere as follows:
//
bsh.shared.myList.add("foo");
```

Comment: I got an error:
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.text.*; import java.util.*; import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtil . . . '' : Constructor error: Can't create instance of an interface: interface java.util.List

Comment: I probably should test even simple code before posting it. Corrected it to use a concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a BeanShell script that performs the initialisation and load it into your other scripts via [source](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#source) ?

Comment: This is what I am doing currently. `source()` evaluates the loaded script in the current namespace and hence , the initialisation code will be executed twice , once from each bsh script.